5G locking Android 14 Tecno Camon 30 5G
How to choose 5G only in preferred networks or even LTE only using set edit?
My phone is Tecno Camon 30 5G.
I hate using 4G, it eats GB consumption, while 5G lock is unlimited.


Note that a lot of networks/cell towers use 5G NSA (non standalone mode) mode which means 5G only works in combination with a 4G connection. A pure 5G connection requires the phone and cell tower to support 5G SA mode.

It's really hard to believe there's an mobile ISP out there that 1) differentiates between data coming from different technologies in the same data plan and, even harder to believe 2) they give you unlimited traffic with the latest technology while limiting traffic to the 2nd best. It would be interesting if you could show us proof of what you're asserting here.
